# Node js image is /blog route is not working?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, formidable

everyone I am building a project while learning nodejs. It is a blogging system. When I am working on /blog route to create a route it doesen't do any action. So, please help. I am pasting the code of files.
**Server.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const morgan = require("morgan");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const cors = require("cors");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
require("dotenv").config();
//bring routes
const blogRoutes = require("./routes/blog");
const authRoutes = require("./routes/auth");
const userRoutes = require("./routes/user");
const categoryRoutes = require("./routes/category");
const tagRoutes = require("./routes/tag");
const fileUpload=require('express-fileupload');
//create app
const app = express(); //Invoke the express app

//middlewares
app.use(morgan("dev")); //I help us in seeing the endpoints

app.use(fileUpload({createParentPath:true}))
app.use(bodyParser.json({extended:true}));//for json 
app.use(
  bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
  })
);//To take body we need to use bodyParser
app.use(cookieParser());

//connect with the database
mongoose
  .connect(process.env.DATABASE, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  })
  .then(
    () => console.log("Database Connected "),
    (err) => {
      console.log(err);
    }
  );
//cors

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") {
  app.use(cors({ origin: `${process.env.CLIENT_URL}` }));
}
//routes middleware
//Use routes middleware at the ends
app.use("/", blogRoutes);
app.use("/", authRoutes);
app.use("/", userRoutes);
app.use("/", categoryRoutes);
app.use("/", tagRoutes);
const port = process.env.PORT || 8000;
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});
```

Now , routes folder .
**blog.js**

```
const express = require("express");
//Now we need router from the expres
const router = express.Router();
//We want that user must be logedIn and admin 
const { requireSignin,adminMiddleware, } = require("../controllers/auth");
const {create}=require('../controllers/blog'); 
router.post("/blog",requireSignin,adminMiddleware,create); 
module.exports=router
```

In models folder file blog to create Schema for the content that user can upload.
**blog.js**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const { ObjectId } = mongoose.Schema;
//Now we are making the schema
const blogSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    //mongoose.Schema is a function that takes object as the argument
    title: {
      type: String,
      trim: true,
      min: 3,
      max: 160,
      required: true,
    },
    slug: {
      //we create database using slug that why index is true
      type: String,
      unique: true,
      index: true,
    },
    body: {
      type: {}, //Here empty object means we can store all types of data
      required: true,
      min: 200,
      max: 2000000,
    },
    expert: {
      //This is the first few lines of the blog
      type: String,
      max: 1000,
    },
    mtitle: { //It is something the like meta tag 
      type: String,
    },
    mdesc:{ //In this we give description 
        type:String 
    },
    photo: {
      //To save the image
      data: Buffer,
      contentType: String,
    },
    categories:[{type:ObjectId,ref:'Category',required:true}], //As each blog can have multiple category and it must refer to Category schema 
    tags:[{type:ObjectId,ref:'Tag',required:true}],
    postedBy:{
        type:ObjectId , 
        ref:'User' //Here refer user modle for information of user 
    }
  },
  { timestamp: true }
);

//Time stamp makes the updated and modified date by default

module.exports = mongoose.model("Blog", blogSchema);
```

Now, to control in controllers folder . Separe file to handle all function realted to blog.
**blog.js**

```
const Blog = require("../models/blog");
const formidable = require("formidable");
const slugify = require("slugify");
const stripHtml = require("string-strip-html");
const _ = require("lodash");
const Category = require("../models/category");
const Tag = require("../models/tag");
const fs = require("fs");
exports.create = (req, res) => {
  let form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
  console.log(form);
  form.keepExtensions = true;

  form.parse(req, (err, fields, files) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(400).json({
        error: "Image could not upload",
      });
    }
    const { title, body, categories, tags } = fields;
    let blog = new Blog(); //Instanciate new blog model
    blog.title = title;
    blog.body = body;
    blog.slug = slugify(title).toLowerCase();
    blog.mtitle = `${title}| ${process.env.APP_NAME}`;
    blog.mdesc = stripHtml(body.substring(0, 160));
    blog.postedBy = req.auth._id;

    //Now we will handle the files
    if (files.photo) {
      if (files.photo.size > 10000000) {
        return res.status(400).json({
          error: "Image should be less than 1 mb in size ",
        });
      }
      blog.photo.data = fs.readFileSync(files.photo.path);
      blog.photo.contentType = files.photo.type;
    }
    blog.save((err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        return res.status(400).json({
          error: err,
        });
      }
      res.json(result);
    });
  });
};
```

All other routes are working fine . So , please help us where I am doing wrong. I will be thank ful to you .

I have try to change the file uploaded by browsing on the internet . I want my code to work properly for this blog route. So , I can create blog .